# Visual Studio Code remove auto-complete

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image][image]

How do i disable this auto complete thing?  I have tried all the settings in VS studio code...

Above is my settings

Below are is my entire settings.json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the VSCode settings look up "emmet". Click under exclude emmet languages "edit in settings.json" and add your language and save it. If your language is not supported check if its added in "include languages" and if it is remove it, if not commment back here.

To have it never show up in any languages add this to settings.json ("emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never")

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Edit:
Where it says:

```
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [

        "markdown"
    ]
```

Change it to:

```
    "emmet.excludeLanguages": [

        "markdown"
        "php"
    ]
```

Hope this works!

Comment: I have edited my question with capture of my settings.json.  with those settings, and having reset vscode I am still seeing the same thing.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Programming language? Php.

Comment: What does your settings.json look like?

Comment: edited main question with complete settings.json